# How to show Image in Panel using button press action

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

I want to show Image on Panel by press Button. I create some code

```
JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("next");
    btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            if(i<files1.length){
                BufferedImage bi;
                try {
                    bi = ImageIO.read(new File(""+files1[i]));
                    System.out.println(files1[i]);
                    JLabel label = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(bi));
                    panel_1.add(label);
                    panel_1.repaint();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            else
                System.out.println("end of picture");
            i++;
        }
    });
```

But after click button image doesn't show.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? I see you keep on adding more labels. Is that what you really want? Or are you trying to get a slide show effect. A little more detail will go a long way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But after click button image doesn't show.

Looks like you are missing the revalidate(). The basic code when adding a component to a visible GUI is:

```
panel.add(....);
panel.revalidate(); // to invoke the layout manager
panel.repaint();
```

Answer (score 1):

My Java is not the best. But obviously I would say something like:

```
if(button.isPressed()) {
    Panel.visible;
}
```

I don't know the exact methods. That's more of a suggestion.

Answer (score -1):

You gave only part of your code in a non-working state. Try to include all the relevant code (in this case include the definition of your panel and i) or strip is down to show the point of what's not working. For me this works:

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        final JLabel label = new JLabel();
        JButton button = new JButton("next");

        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

                BufferedImage bi = null;
                try {
                    bi = ImageIO.read(new File("pathtofile"));
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                label.setIcon(new ImageIcon(bi));
            }
        });

        frame.setContentPane(new JPanel());
        frame.getContentPane().add(button);
        frame.getContentPane().add(label);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

However, consider that JLabel is not designed to display images a la gallery style. Consider JScrollPane as shown [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html).